# Can I set screensaver to start if I'm not watching video?

Tags: xfce, screensaver

I'm using Xfce and the screen goes to blank if I'm not doing anything on my mouse or keyboard for a while. How can I set that thins won't happen? Also, is it possible to set the screensaver such that if I'm watching video on the internet, the screensaver won't go on?

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Caffeine**, it works both with gnome-screensaver and xscreensaver. If you can't install it, there are lots of independent scripts that you can download and use.

If you can't install directly, try with this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine python-glade2
```

Here is a well known [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hotice/lightsOn/master/lightsOn.sh)